# How can I convert this HTML snippet into bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can this table get converted into bootstrap rows and cols? I am not too familiar with bootstrap but I'd like to try and convert it as best as possible but not sure where to begin. thanks you very much for any help.
 I have pasted my html and css . thanks

```
<div id="section1">
     <header>WEEKLY HOURS</header>
     <table class="section1table">
    <tr class="last-row">
        <th>Clocked</th>
        <th>Regular</th>
        <th>Overtime</th>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>

        <th colspan=4>Off-Clock</th>
        <th class="total"><strong>Total</strong></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="last-row">
        <td id="clockHours">clockHrs</td>
        <td id="regularHours">regularHrs</td>
        <td id="overtime">overtimeHrs</td>
        <td id="Incentive">incentiveHrs</td>
        <td id="holiday">holidayHrs</td>
        <td id="personal">sickHrs</td>
        <td id="vacation">vacationHrs</td>
        <td colspan=4>offClockHrs</td>
        <td class="total">totalHrs</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

```
    #printPage 
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 910px;
  margin-bottom: 0.4%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'sans-serif';
}
#timetitle
{
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}
#name
{
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 15px

}
div#namesection
{
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 670px; 
    margin-left:0%;


}

div#section1
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 870px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;


}
div#section1 header
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
table.section1table td 
{
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;

}
table.section1table th 
{
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: left;
}
div#section2 /*labeled wrong, this is the sec2 header*/
{
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  width: 870px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-bottom: 0;


}
table.section1table 
{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-top: 0.15%;
}

div#section2 header /*labeled wrong, this is the actual box in sec2*/
{
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

table.section2table 
{
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: .15%;
}

table.section2table th,
table.section2table td 
{
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  /* The following rule (white-space) is used to allow the last cell   */
  /* to fill the remaining width.                                      */

  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.section2table th 
{
  /* padding to keep THs right aligned with TDs                        */
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

table.section2table td 
{
  padding: 5px;
}

table.section2table tr.last-row th,
table.section2table tr.last-row td 
{
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

table.section2table tr.last-row th.total,
table.section2table tr.last-row td.total 
{
  /* The following rule (width) is used to allow the last cell to fill */
  /* the remaining width.                                              */

  width: 99%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

How can this table get converted into bootstrap rows and cols?

Comment: Read the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: As written, this question seems overly-broad.  Rather than just stating the problem, can you show steps that you've attempted but which do not work?  Resources you have read but which do not help?

Comment: I am basically looking to put my html table and convert it in bootstrap form

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should go through [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and get familiar with it, doing this you will be able to do this yourself.

Secondly if its only about this table then bellow code will do your work.

what is going on here is the bootstrap [grid structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/), `<tr>` is replaced by `<div class="row">`, row is divided in 12 columns, so here we are using `<div class="col-sm-1">`, and for the cell with `colspan=4` you can use `class="col-sm-4"`.

here in this snippet we have small display area so I have used `col-sm-*`, for larger display size you can used `col-md-*`/`col-lg-*`. Go through the bootstrap docs for more details.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Clocked</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Regular</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Overtime</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Incentive</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Holiday</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Personal</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">Vacation</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">Off-Clock</div>
    <div class="total col-sm-1 text-center"><strong>Total</strong></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="clockHours">clockHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="regularHours">regularHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="overtime">overtimeHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="Incentive">incentiveHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="holiday">holidayHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="personal">sickHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" id="vacation">vacationHrs</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">offClockHrs</div>
    <div class="total col-sm-1 text-center">totalHrs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```